# Handling differences in JSON nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

JSON Data Snippet

```
    "calcNutrients": [
      {
        "name": "Energy (kJ)",
        "valuePer100": "2557",
        "valuePerServing": "596"
      },
      {
        "name": "Energy (kcal)",
        "valuePer100": "615",
        "valuePerServing": "143"
      },
      {
        "name": "Fat (g)",
        "valuePer100": "46.2",
        "valuePerServing": "10.8"
      },
      {
        "name": " of which saturates (g)",
        "valuePer100": "16.4",
        "valuePerServing": "3.8"
      },
      {
        "name": "Carbohydrate (g)",
        "valuePer100": "0.2",
        "valuePerServing": "0.1",
        "qualPerServing": "<"
      },
      {
        "name": " of which sugars (g)",
        "valuePer100": "0.1",
        "valuePerServing": "0.1",
        "qualPerServing": "<"
      },
      {
        "name": "Protein (g)",
        "valuePer100": "49.7",
        "valuePerServing": "11.6"
      },
      {
        "name": "Salt (g)",
        "valuePer100": "3",
        "valuePerServing": "0.7"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I am outputting to a table at the moment which has 9 columns

```
kJ | Kcal | Fat | Fat Sats | Carbs | Carbs Sugar | Fibre | Protein | Salt
```

As you can see from the snippet above **there is no Fibre listed** which is causing me the problem and hence the question.

How can I deal with this so that I can present 0 if Fibre is not present in the JSON? But still populate the table correctly.

JSON is in the same order as the table column headings but some may not be present.

I just can't get my head around it

Edit:

Added code for inserting the nutrient information into the table.
Table is simple HTML table with HTML hardcoded columns/headers etc  (the table structure is **NOT** populated from the JSON

```
foreach ($obj2['products'][0]['calcNutrition']['calcNutrients'] as $nutrients) {
  echo "<td>" . $nutrients[$valuePerServing] . "</td>";
}
```

print_r result (no fibre)

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Energy (kJ) [valuePer100] => 2557 [valuePerServing] => 596 )
[1] => Array ( [name] => Energy (kcal) [valuePer100] => 615 [valuePerServing] => 143 )
[2] => Array ( [name] => Fat (g) [valuePer100] => 46.2 [valuePerServing] => 10.8 )
[3] => Array ( [name] => of which saturates (g) [valuePer100] => 16.4 [valuePerServing] => 3.8 )
[4] => Array ( [name] => Carbohydrate (g) [valuePer100] => 0.2 [valuePerServing] => 0.1 [qualPerServing] => < )
[5] => Array ( [name] => of which sugars (g) [valuePer100] => 0.1 [valuePerServing] => 0.1 [qualPerServing] => < )
[6] => Array ( [name] => Protein (g) [valuePer100] => 49.7 [valuePerServing] => 11.6 )
[7] => Array ( [name] => Salt (g) [valuePer100] => 3 [valuePerServing] => 0.7 ) )
```

print_r (with fibre)

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Energy (kJ) [valuePer100] => 885 [valuePerServing] => 1107 )
[1] => Array ( [name] => Energy (kcal) [valuePer100] => 213 [valuePerServing] => 266 )
[2] => Array ( [name] => Fat (g) [valuePer100] => 15.2 [valuePerServing] => 19 )
[3] => Array ( [name] => saturates (g) [valuePer100] => 5.1 [valuePerServing] => 6.4 )
[4] => Array ( [name] => Carbohydrate (g) [valuePer100] => 0 [valuePerServing] => 0 )
[5] => Array ( [name] => sugars (g) [valuePer100] => 0 [valuePerServing] => 0 )
[6] => Array ( [name] => Fibre (g) [valuePer100] => 0 [valuePerServing] => 0 )
[7] => Array ( [name] => Protein (g) [valuePer100] => 19 [valuePerServing] => 23.8 )
[8] => Array ( [name] => Salt (g) [valuePer100] => 0.3 [valuePerServing] => 0.3 ) )
```

//Further Edit

Granted I can use the below and array_splice it into where I need it if it doesn't exist, but is there any other better way of doing this?.  If for instance the Protein listing was missing?

```
$fibreInsert = array(
  array (
      "name" => "Fibre (g)",
      "valuePer100" => "0",
      "valuePerServing" => "0"
  )
);
```

**Answered by trincot**
I used his advice to create the following which works perfectly.

```
$isFirst = true;
    foreach ($source['calcNutrients'] as $nutrients)
      {
        if ($isFirst)
        {
            $isFirst = false;
            continue;
        }
        foreach($cols as $col) {
            if (stristr($nutrients["name"],  $col))
            {
                echo "<td>"  . $nutrients[$servingType] . "</td>";
                break;
            } else {
              echo '';
            }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Show us the code which fills your table.

Comment: I've added the PHP code I am using to iterate through the nutrients.  The table is simply HTML and the structure is not populated from the JSON, it is hardcoded.

Comment: Generally If element in object exists than echo it

Comment: If $servingType == 'Fibre'&&!==NULL echo... else echo 0

Comment: is  FIBRE   one of  ` $nutrients['name'] ` value ? if so you can check if it exist or not

Comment: @Zydnar sorry the $servingType was for something else (I have amended that now)

`$fibreInsert = array(
    array (
        "name" => "Fibre (g)",
        "valuePer100" => "0",
        "valuePerServing" => "0"
    )
    );`


Granted I can array_splice with the follow array inserted after the 5th index, seems like a sloppy way of doing it?

Comment: `$key = array_search('Fibre (g)', array_column($source, 'name'));` looks like a good way of checking would just have to set it up for all of the nutrients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the items are ordered in the right order, you could do the following:

- Define another array that has all the 9 name values that can occur, in the correct order
- Iterate that array, while keeping an array pointer in the *calcNutrients* array. If the names match, then print the `td` element like you did, and move the array pointer. If the names do not match, then this is a sign that that particular name is missing, so print an empty `td` element and don't move the array pointer.

Here is the code:

```
$cols = Array("Energy (kJ)", "Energy (kcal)", "Fat (g)", "of which saturates (g)",
     "Carbohydrate (g)", "of which sugars (g)", "Fibre (g)", "Protein (g)", "Salt (g)");

$result = $obj2['products'][0]['calcNutrition']['calcNutrients'];

reset($result); // we're gong to use an array pointer
foreach($cols as $col) {
    if (current($result)["name"] == $col) {
        echo "<td>" . current($result)["valuePerServing"] . "</td>\n";
        next($result); // move the array pointer.
    } else {
        echo "<td></td>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, looks a cleaner than what I am doing right now with the array_slice.